# A function for onehotencoding and labelencoding in a dataframe

Tags: python, sklearn-pandas, one-hot-encoding, label-encoding

I keep getting `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'column'` when I run the function on a column in a dataframe

```py
def reform (column, dataframe): 
    if dataframe.column.nunique() > 2 and dataframe.column.dtypes == object:
        enc.fit(dataframe[['column']])
        enc.categories_
        onehot = enc.transform(dataframe[[column]]).toarray()
        dataframe[enc.categories_] = onehot
    elif dataframe.column.nunique() == 2 and dataframe.column.dtypes == object :
        le.fit_transform(dataframe[['column']])
    else:
        print('Column cannot be reformed')
    return dataframe
```

Comment: just use `columns` instead of `column`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

- `dataframe.column` to `dataframe.loc[:,column]`.
- `dataframe[['column']]` to  `dataframe.loc[:,[column]]`

**For more help, please provide more information.** Such as: What is `enc` (show your imports)? What does `dataframe` look like (show a small example, perhaps with `dataframe.head(5)`)?

**Details:**
Since `column` is an input (probably a string), you need to use it correctly when asking for that column from the dataframe object. If you just use `dataframe.column` it will try to find the column *actually named* 'column', but if you ask for it `dataframe.loc[:,column]`, it will use the string that is represented by the input parameter named column.

- With `dataframe.loc[:,column]`, you get a Pandas Series, and with `dataframe.loc[:,[column]]` you get a Pandas DataFrame.
- The pandas attribute 'columns', used as `dataframe.columns` (note the 's' at the end) just returns a list of the names of all columns in your dataframe, probably not what you want here.

**TIPS:**

- Try to name input parameters so that you know what they are.
- When developing a function, try setting the input to something static, and iterate the code until you get desired output. E.g.

  ```
    input_df = my_df
    column_name = 'some_test_column'
    if input_df.loc[:,column_name].nunique() > 2 and input_df.loc[:,column_name].dtypes == object:
        enc.fit(input_df.loc[:,[column_name]])
        onehot = enc.transform(input_df.loc[:,[column_name]]).toarray()
        input_df.loc[:, enc.categories_] = onehot
    elif input_df.loc[:,column_name].nunique() == 2 and input_df.loc[:,column_name].dtypes == object :
        le.fit_transform(input_df.loc[:,[column_name]])
    else:
        print('Column cannot be transformed')
  ```
- Look up on how to use SciKit Learn Pipelines, with ColumnTransformer. It will help make the workflow easier (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/compose.html).